# Log in program on delphi with data source

Tags: database, string, delphi, authentication

I would like to know how i could create a **log in** *program* with some **method of data storage** that *stores the* **login information** of **registered users** and **then accesses it** when users type in their log in details for verification?
I do know how to create a basic login program with labels,buttons and edit boxes but do not know how to store information about the users registered and then access this again.

Comment: For now I see **two** questions. Build an application and storing data. Which one should be answered here?

Comment: Sounds like a good exercise as an introduction to using databases with Delphi. You may want to start by learning about DB-Aware components http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/Using_Database_Components_DB_Aware_Controls_in_Delphi.htm

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have included the 'database' tag in your question implies that you already know what the solution is - a database. If your program already uses a database, add a table for users which includes their real name, their user name and their encoded password. Your login screen will have to query this table to check whether the user is valid. Make sure that you use parameters to the query; this way you avoid the possibility of sql injection (query 'little bobby tables').